# define sum function in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, numbers, sum, function

Please help, I am a Ruby student, I know how to do the .sum method but not this:
how do you define a sum function for an array so that providing any elements will result in the sum of them. The format should be sum([array inputs]) return sum of array elements. For ex: sum([ ]) should return 0, sum([1,2,3]) returns 6 (#again, not [1,2,3].sum). I am so stuck in the box, thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Look for the source of `Array#sum` :)

Comment: What `sum` method do you know? Are you mentioning Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution with usage of [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
def sum(array)
  array.inject(0){|sum, el| sum + el}
end
```

Or, as suggested, shorter and more elegant form:

```
def sum(array)
  array.inject(0, :+)
end
```

Comment: or `array.sum` -- see answer from NikDP

Answer (score 2):

Use array sum method.

```
arr = [1,2,3]
arr.sum


def sum(arr)
  arr.sum
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
def sum(array)
  array.reduce(0, :+)
end
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need `0`. You can do `array.reduce(:+)`.

Comment: @sawa `[].reduce(:+) # => nil`

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum(arr)
 sum = 0
 arr.each{|element| sum=sum+element }
 return sum
end
```

Comment: While this works, so imperative a way of doing thing is not idiomatic in Ruby (and that `return` is definitely **not** idiomatic).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is more of my level :)